# How to return Sensitive Info Keychain value in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-keychain

I have a token I stored using the sensitive info keychain but when I try to get the token I keep getting either undefined or {"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}

My code:

```
// Get Token from storage
const getToken = async () => await RNSInfo.getItem('token', {});
const token = getToken();

console.log(token);
```

When I write a function and include above code inside it I can successfully return it but I need the token for code outside that function

```
// check if post is liked
const checkIsLiked = async () => {
  const token = await getToken();
  try {
    axios
      .get(url, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: 'token ' + JSON.parse(token),
        },
      })
      .then(res => {
        const likeValue = res.data;
        setIsLike(likeValue);
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may forget to add `await` before `getToken()` in the first part of code.

```
const getToken = async () => await RNSInfo.getItem('token', {});
const token = await getToken(); //add 'await' in this line

console.log(token);
```

If you are using functions which cannot be simply change to asynchronous like `useEffect`. You may follow the codes below.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const doWhenFocus = async() => {
      const token = await RNSInfo.getItem('token', {});
      console.log(token);
    };
    doWhenFocus();
  });
```